# Why won't this SQL JOIN query work?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to get every 'Forum_THREADS' a user posted to, or replied to.

When they reply, it's in the 'Forum_REPLIES' table.

Here's my query:

```
    $threads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FORUM_Threads
        INNER JOIN FORUM_Replies
        ON
        FORUM_Threads.Poster = $userRow->ID
        OR
        (
            FORUM_Replies.Poster = $userRow->ID
            AND
            FORUM_Replies.ThreadID = FORUM_Threads.ID
        )
    ");
```

At the moment it's not working properly, and when it does, I'd imagine it'd fetch some threads multiple times. Is there any better way to do this where it won't fetch threads multiple times, and it'll work properly?

`Forum_REPLIES` is just a duplicate of `Forum_THREADS` with the 'ThreadID' field.

Comment: Whats is not working properly ?

Comment: Not fetching any results (They definitly are). I tried with LEFT JOIN too but it was giving me timezone errors every time I used mysql_fetch_object. I'm contacting my host about that.

Comment: Could You show tables definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you must join on a column in `FORUM_Replies`, not a scalar value (`$userRow->ID`).

It looks like you're using a JOIN where you really should be using a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed ON would work as WHERE. It seems to be fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I guess this should work

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM FORUM_Threads
    INNER JOIN FORUM_Replies
    ON
    FORUM_Threads.ThreadId = FORUM_Replies.Thread_Id
    where
    FORUM_Threads.Poster = $userRow->ID
    OR
    FORUM_Replies.Poster = $userRow->ID
```

Assuming ThreadId is the name of the key, You need to do Join on Keys.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is what you want instead:

```
$threads = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM FORUM_Threads
    WHERE FORUM_Threads.Poster = $userRow->ID
    OR EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM FORUM_Replies
        WHERE FORUM_Replies.ThreadID = FORUM_Threads.ID
        AND FORUM_Replies.Poster = $userRow->ID
    )
");
```

If you use a join with the Replies table you will get duplicate threads if a user replied to a thread more than once.